# How to get both hidden and nonhidden files in a single call

Tags: ruby

I have a directory with both hidden (name starting with `.`) and non-hidden files as follows:

```
$ ls -a1
.
..
.hidden
not-hidden
```

How can I get a listing of all of them in a single call?

I expected `Dir['*']` to return all files, but it doesn't:

```
Dir['*']
# => ["not-hidden"]
```

The best I can think of is:

```
Dir['*'] + Dir['.*']
# => ["not-hidden", ".", "..", ".hidden"]
```

And I also expected there to be a way to use a regex, but I cannot find one, and it's not possible to use `select` and `grep` because there is no call capable of getting both hidden and non-hidden from which to select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) with the [`FNM_DOTMATCH`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File/Constants.html#FNM_DOTMATCH) flag:

```
Dir.glob('*', File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
#=> [".", "..", ".hidden", "not-hidden"]
```

or [`Dir::entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries):

```
Dir.entries('.')
#=> [".", "..", ".hidden", "not-hidden"]
```

You can also combine patterns using `{p,q}`, so `Dir['{*,.*}']` would also work.